# UWP application can't find USB devices

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, usb

So I have badge/card reader and I want to use it for my application. The device has Com-port connection possibility.  When I use `SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector` with the com-port name device is found. But when I use `UsbDevice` with vendorId and productId or `SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromUsbVidPid` enumeration returns nothing. Seems like I've tried everything I could find and nothing helped yet.
Also, I've tried to find 3 different devices just to see if  `UsbDevice` will find any and only 1 phone (out of 2 phones and 1 reader) was found. I also tried to get the device by passing the Id that I can get from the device found by `SerialDevice` to the `UsbDevice.GetDeviceSelector` and that did nothing.

Comment: Can you post some code snippet?

Comment: @anangupadhyaya
`UInt32 vid = 0x0403;

 UInt32 pid = 0x1234; string selector = UsbDevice.GetDeviceSelector(vid, pid); DeviceInformationCollection devices = (DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector)).AsTask().Result; DeviceInformation deviceInfo = devices.FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: @vlad-borovsky Congratulations on your first question on Stack Overflow! You can edit your question to include the source code you have written in your comment (you can use block code instead of inline code). It will make your question better for sure. Also, it would be nice to finish your question with an actual question sentence. Currently, you have described your problem, but did not actually ask the question.